# Selecting text between 2nd and 3rd occurrence of delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select the text between the second and third occurance of a delimeter (-) in SQL server.

For example, if I have the string `aaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd` I would like to return `cccc`, but I can't understand how to make a substring work when I have more than 2 of the delimeters.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Part of asking on StackOverflow is showing your work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why don't you make this logic on AP?

Comment: Look up `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`.

Comment: Use CHARINDEX a couple of times.

Comment: here's something for starters  DECLARE @X as nvarchar(100) = 'aaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd';

SELECT CHARINDEX('-',@X, CHARINDEX('-', @X) + 1);

Comment: If there's always going to be 3 delimiters, `PARSENAME` would likely work very well here as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you always the same number of elements you could leverage PARSENAME like this.

```
select parsename(replace('aaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd', '-', '.'), 2)
```

But if your real data is not that consistent you need to use a real splitter.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Sorry, I should have been more specific in my question. There are occasions where there will be an extra '-', so this will work for all others, but not those.

Comment: @DSTL Can you post some further examples of your data where the extra '-' occurs?

Answer (score 1):

If `parsename()` (+1) is not a valid option, perhaps a little XML.

Here are two illustrations, both return the same results

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('aaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd')

Select SomeCol
      ,Pos2 = cast('<x>' + replace(A.SomeCol,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
      ,Pos3 = cast('<x>' + replace(A.SomeCol,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
 From  @YourTable A


Select SomeCol
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos2 = XMLData.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                       ,Pos3 = XMLData.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                  From  (values (cast('<x>' + replace(A.SomeCol,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) B1(XMLData)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol             Pos2    Pos3
aaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd  bbbb    cccc
```